# Sort array in ASC order depending on two key values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have one array that is stored in one variable. The array is following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-11
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-09
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-10
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => GURVINDER
        [today_date] => 2018-01-11
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => GURVINDER
        [today_date] => 2018-01-10
    )
)
```

I have done with sorting of array in ascending with `employee_name` that is running very fine with this code:

```
$attendances = "above array";
uasort($attendances, function($a, $b) {
     return strcmp($a["employee_name"], $b["employee_name"]);
 }); // this code is sorting in ascending order with employee_name.
```

Now what i want is that every `employee_name` should be ascending order and each `employee_name` `today_date` should also be in ascending order. My expected output is like that:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-09
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => Amit
        [today_date] => 2018-01-11
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => GURVINDER
        [today_date] => 2018-01-10
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [employee_name] => GURVINDER
        [today_date] => 2018-01-11
    )
)
```

Please help me how to resolve this problem. I will not go with SQL query for some reasons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine based on your output requirement. Try this:

```
array_multisort(array_column($attendances, 'employee_name'),  SORT_ASC,
            array_column($attendances, 'today_date'), SORT_ASC,
            $attendances);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($attendances);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/935967

Comment: Yes this is correct.+1. why this isn't stryke in my mind as i already used it multiple times :):)